# SSD doesn’t work correctly: Deleted files come back after restart and I can’t run any games

Tags: windows-10, ssd

I am using Windows 10 and the SSD it is on doesn't work as expected. When I deleted files, they re-appear after a restart of the computer (same with Game Launchers like Steam, the games don’t uninstall).

I tried the Windows Repair tool but it says, it can't scan and repair the SSD. Everything I installed before this accident works perfectly (games etc…).
After I looked at the settings of my SSD at the Events and it said that at 19.10.19 the SSD "could not be migrated", maybe this could help. The Date would fit because around the end of october my SSD started acting weird.
Here is the message:

```
Das Gerät SCSI\Disk&Ven_&Prod_SATAFIRM___S11\5&221d478d&0&050000 could not be migrated because of a partly or ambiguous concordance.

ID of the last Device Instance: USBSTOR\Disk&Ven_Generic&Prod_USB_Flash_Disk&Rev_7.76\7&1ea7dbf7&0
Class-GUID: {4d36e967-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}
Savepath: 
Migrationrank: 0xF000FC00FFFFF120
available: false
Status: 0xC0000719
```

^This was translated from german, sorry if there are some mistakes

I am still able to view files with the files explorer and I dont get any errors when I try to open folders. Anyone know how to fix this problem?

Comment: What "accident" are you referring to exactly?

Comment: The accident is the moment, when the SSD behaved like that. Its nothing important

Comment: Sounds like you have software that is rolling back the image of the system itself, and has nothing to do with it being a SSD specifically, can you confirm you have any such software installed on your system?

Comment: hm, Im pretty sure I dont have anything installed like that. I dont have a reason to do resetting my SSD and I also didnt plan to do this

Comment: Is this a personal PC?  Create a text file on the SSD, reboot the machine, the text file should still exist.  How old is the SSD?  How many writes have you made, use the appropriate tools, to determine the amount of writes the SSD has seen in it's lifetime.

Comment: 1. Yes this is a personal PC 2. I tried that with the .txt file and rebooted the pc. It is still there. 3. The SSD is 1 year and maybe ~3 months old

Comment: Edit your question to include all of that vital information, including the amount of data, the SSD has seen written to it.  If you now delete the file, you just created, does the file come back after a reboot?

Comment: ok. So I just found out, that the SSD was on 19.10.19 "not migrated". Maybe this could help

Comment: You will have to provide the require information in the body of your question.  I personally have no idea what you are referring to exactly, which is a problem, because I am sure others are confused as well.

Comment: This looks like `STATUS_CONTEXT_MISMATCH` which is probably a different translation of the OP error message. Is this device used with any non-windows OS? See for example ( https://borncity.com/win/2017/03/15/windows-10-error-device-not-migrated/ )

Comment: Have you ran a basic SMART test? Do new files disappear after reboot as well?

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you could have a virus or some sort of malware.
Run a virus scan on your system.

If that is not the case it could be some sort of syncing software or backup software that you have running. Make sure you don't have any backups setup on your computer to sync to a cloud service such as OneDrive, etc.

Check and make sure your account has permissions to delete said files.

Lastly make sure your drive is not full, and that the recycle bin is empty. 
Alternatively, locate some files, select them, hold **shift+DEL** this will permanently delete the files omitting the recycle bin.